# apache spark add column which is a complex calculation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a following dataset `df1` in Spark:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- t: string (nullable = true)
 |-- x: double (nullable = false)
 |-- y: double (nullable = false)
 |-- z: double (nullable = false)
```

and I need to create a column which will be a kind of calculation result of

`sqrt(x)+cqrt(y)+z*constantK`

I'm trying something like following:

```
val constantK=100500
val df2= df1.select($"id", (scala.math.sqrt($"x")+scala.math.cqrt($"y")+$"z"*constantK ))
```

however, I got a type mismatch error

```
<console>:59: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
 required: Double
       val df2= df1.select($"id", (scala.math.sqrt($"x")+scala.math.cqrt($"y")+$"z"*constantK ))
```

what is the proper way of adding columns with complex calculations which are based on the values of other columns in the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying tu use Scala.math functions in Spark SQL. SparkSQL has its own operations and types:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sqrt

df1.select($"id", (sqrt($"x")+sqrt($"y")+$"z"*constantK ))
```

The operator '*' is supported. Take a look to https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html